# Vacuous statements and explosion

Tags: logic, proof-verification, fake-proofs

So my understanding of vacuous statements is as follows: For any statement $P$, the statement $(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))$. This can be argued as follows: Assume for contradiction $\neg [(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))]$. Then by DeMorgan, $(\exists x \in \emptyset)(\neg P(x))$, i.e. if a "for all" statement fails, there must be a witness to the failure. But $\not \exists x \in \emptyset$, so we cannot have a witness, a contradiction. Thus $(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))$.

But this seems as if it would entail explosion, as $[(\forall x \in \emptyset)(\neg P(x))] \Rightarrow \neg [(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))]$. So it seems as if I've shown the contradiction $[(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))] \land \neg [(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))]$. Why does this not imply explosion?

Answer (score 3):

You assert that $$[(\forall x \in \emptyset)(\neg P(x))] \Rightarrow \neg [(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(X))]$$
without providing any justification for it. It's simply false.

Comment: Isn't the former stronger than the latter?

Comment: If $\emptyset$ were replaced by a nonempty set, yes. As it stands, no. $(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(X))$ is true, so its negation is false.

Comment: Wouldn't its negation (i.e. $\neg [ \neg [(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))]]$) be $(\exists x \in \emptyset)(P(x))$, which also can't be true?

Comment: No. The negation of $(\forall x \in \emptyset)(P(x))$ is $(\exists x \in \emptyset)(\neg P(x))$, which is false. The negation of that in turn is $(\forall x \in \emptyset)(\neg \neg P(x))$, which is true because it's of the form "for all $x \in \emptyset$, something".

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let us break the chain of your logic down.   It is just two steps.   You have:

$$\begin{align*}
\forall x\in D:P(x) ~ \implies & ~ \exists x\in D:P(x) \tag 1 \\[1ex] \exists x\in D:P(x) ~ \iff & ~ \neg \forall x\in D:\neg P(x) \tag 2 \\[1ex] ~ \\[0ex]\hline \\[1ex] \therefore \forall x\in\varnothing:P(x) \implies & ~ \neg \forall x\in \varnothing: \neg P(x) \tag {C!} \end{align*}$$

Now, step $(2)$ is from the Dual Negation equivalence.   That is okay.

The issue lies in that the weakening in step $(1)$ is only sound if the domain $D$ is not empty<sup>†</sup>.   It is not justifiable if $D$ is in fact empty.

⟨ † : That caveat is too often omitted when it is implicit that we are dealing with a non-empty domain.   It is something to watch for when it is possible that the domain may be empty. ⟩

---

"Anything in the empty set has property P" does not actually imply that "There's something in the empty set with property P".